# Deploying Node.js app to elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I deploy my Node.JS app to Elastic beanstalk, the only thing I get is a nginx 502 bad gateway. The app runs fine locally. I read the tutorial (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express.html), but it didn't solve any of my problems. What can cause a 502 bad gateway and/or how can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: 502 indicates that nginx isn't able to talk to Nodejs. I'm guessing that Nodejs is having issues starting up. What do the logs say? Could you post them here? You can tail the last 100 lines which should give you a good indication: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.loggingS3.title.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't hard code the port number.

```
// BAD
server.listen(1704, function() { ... })

// GOOD
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 1704, function() { ... })
```